# Angular: How to import and use Carousel from ng-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I'm tasked with styling an Angular 6 sandbox using ng-bootstrap. That part has been going very well. Now I'm trying to install a carousel and I'm hitting a wall.  I'm using the ng-bootstrap carousel, as i figure that's probably the best choice, but any other suggestions are welcome, such as a "pure javascript" carousel.

Note, this is my setup:

Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 10.3.0
OS: darwin x64

I located the ng install instructions:

[https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples)

But it seems I need more things spelled out. The first part worked:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

But the next part threw me off:

> The only remaining part is to list the imported module in your root
>   module and any additional application modules that make use of the
>   components in this library. The exact method will be slightly
>   different for the root (top-level) module for which you should end up
>   with the code similar to (notice NgbModule.forRoot()):

What is the 'root module'?  I assume that would be app.module.ts.  So I added the new code to app.module.ts:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

And I see there is another version of the code to add to all modules other than the root. No problem there. I checked my site, it still functions.

Note, I also assume I need to do nothing with app.component.ts, correct? I initially thought I needed to add the import to it:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

And it did not break the site, though I don't think it was needed so I removed it.

So, app.module.ts should be good to go.  Next, to add the actual carousel code as found on the example page:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples

Now, I'm at a loss as to the best way to barebones test it. Should I use the core module and/or component as my component?  Or should I generate a NEW component?  I saw a tutorial for adding a carousel to Angular 5 that simply added code to the core module/component so that's what I'm trying now. Could be a big mistake? Please let me know.

At any rate, if I add the carousel-basic.html to appl.component.html, and carousel-basic.ts to the app.component.ts, I get errors. Specifically,

```
./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './carousel-basic.html'
```

And if I change the path to ./component.html it doesn't help.

So really at this point, I'm missing something fundamental but having a hard time asking the right questions.

Can anybody point me to some guidance?

Thank you

Comment: Well, you have to make those files yourself, inside your source code. Then add the code stated in the example to the corresponding files, and add `NgbdCarouselBasic` to the declarations array of your `AppModule`. And as a last step you add `<ngbd-carousel-basic></ngbd-carousel-basic>` to your `app.component.html`

Answer (score 0):

(1) Best to add a new component.ts file (code below)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
selector: 'app-slider',
templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
styles: ['']
})

export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

images = ['https://www.akberiqbal.com/AkberIqbal.jpg', 'https://www.akberiqbal.com/AkberIqbal-og.jpg' ,'https://www.akberiqbal.com/AkberIqbal.jpg', 'https://www.akberiqbal.com/AkberIqbal-og.jpg']

constructor(private config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
  // customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
  this.config.interval = 10000;
  this.config.wrap = false;
  this.config.keyboard = false;
  this.config.pauseOnHover = false;
}

ngOnInit(): void { }
```

}

(2) insert the HTML into the component.html (from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples)

(3) in your app.component.ts, add

(4) in the folder where you are working...

```
npm install bootstrap@4
```

(5) go to index.html and add

your code should work as intended...

Comment: (6) dont forget to add new component to app.module.ts also

Comment: I have added the stackblitz with actual issues being reflected, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57523263/updating-latest-value-to-ngfor-element-and-displaying-it , if now u can suggest, thanks :)